# Compilar react y unir con laravel

Tags: laravel, reactjs, apache

Tengo todo mi front en react listo, tengo todo mi back en laravel listo.
Estoy utilizando laravel 10 y react con vite, como puedo unir todo en una sola url. Estuve buscando por todos lados y no encuentro nada que indique como hacerlo.
Entiendo que hay que ejecutar el comando

```
npm run build
```

Para que react compile y genere los archivos, todos estos archivos pegarlos en la carpeta public de mi proyecto de laravel 10.

Pero ahi me quede, como hago para que al ingresar a la url de mi proyecto de laravel levante mis vistas de react.

El proyecto de laravel esta utilizando xampp para iniciar.

Comment: Podes montar react en cuaquier etiqueta html de una platilla blade que sirva laravel.